# Access Dyson server from React Native ios

Tags: react-native, xmlhttprequest

I'm using Dyson to host a little mock server for my React Native app, and trying to fetch from the server. The server appears to be running well and when I visit my desired url, `http://localhost:3000/stations`, in my browser, I get a nice JSON response.

In my React Native action, though, I get `Network request failed`:

```js
export function fetchStations() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "GET_STATIONS_START" });
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/stations")
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(json => {
        dispatch({ type: "GET_STATIONS_SUCCESS", payload: json.stations });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.warn(error);
        dispatch({ type: "GET_STATIONS_FAILURE", payload: error });
      });
  };
}
```

Using a static local URL works, and using, say, the Google Maps API works (even though it's not what I want, it's just a sample API to try).

I would think I may be calling the url wrong but it works in the browser so that seems doubtful. My *guess* is that is has something to do with iOS not liking http requests (only accepting https), unless you set some setting somewhere (I've been through this in native iOS development).

If this is the problem, how do I fix it from React Native? Or, what is the actual problem?

PS. I'm using dyson rather than json-server because for some reason I can't get json-server to work. See my other post. Somewhere here :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The device (simulator) doesn't have access to `localhost` so I had to set my url to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/stations` and it works like a dream.